# Codificar uma URL é importante?

Tags: c#, .net, url

A maioria das linguagens tem métodos para codificar e decodificar uma URL, como no caso do C# `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(string value)` e `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(string encodedValue)`.

Eu percebi que quando utilizo alguns métodos da linguagem para **Uri**, ele supostamente utiliza essa codificação.

Por exemplo ele codifica uma url assim:
`http://example.com/index?param1=abc&url=example.com/page/blabla`
para:
`http://example.com/index?param1=abc&url=example.com%2page%2blabla`

Consigo decodificar sem problemas com o `WebUtility.UrlDecode()`, e volta a ser como antes.

Porém por qual motivo ele faz isto? Tem alguma importância em codificar a URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A importância é funcionar certo:

Comparando com uma linguagem de programação: é a mesma coisa que codificar aspas dentro de uma string. Para que a interpretação das aspas funcione, você não pode ter uma string assim num código convencional:

```
texto = "olá, José "Jones" da silva"
```

Nesse caso você tem que codificar as aspas do `"Jones"` para que não sejam confundida com as aspas de fechamento.

Mesma coisa no seu exemplo:

```
 http://example.com/index?param1=abc&url=example.com/page/blabla
      ^^           ^                                ^    ^
```

da forma acima, as barras são partes do endereço como um todo.

Já, assim, as barras são parte apenas do parâmetro `url`:

```
http://example.com/index?param1=abc&url=example.com%2Fpage%2Fblabla
                                                   ^^^    ^^^
```

o `%2f` representa o caractere `/` depois de codificado, e não vai ser confundido como parte do endereço (da mesma forma o caractere `&` no exemplo dado seria entendido como separador de parâmetros, então teria que ser convertido para `%23`, assim como o sinal `=` teria que ser convertido para `%3d`, e assim por diante).

### Geralmente você dá o encode apenas nos valores:

Seja nas variáveis ou nas partes separadas por / quando for o caso.

```
http://example.com/index?param1=abc&url=example.com%2Fpage%2Fblabla
                   ^^^^^        ^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Dependendo do contexto você até poderia codificar o nome dos parâmetros também, mas por uma questão de sanidade (sua e da aplicação) o usual é colocar nomes legíveis e sem ambiguidade.

Em resumo, você converte dependendo única e exclusivamente dependendo da intenção da sua aplicação. É um dado que vai num parâmetro? Precisa codificar. É outra parte do endereço? Aí já vai do contexto da sua aplicação.

O que você não vai fazer é dar encode no URL todo, senão vai mexer em partes que não precisa. Por exemplo, se der o encode no endereço inicial do seu exemplo, vai ficar assim (e não vai funcionar corretamente):

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Findex%3Fparam1%3Dabc%26url%3Dexample.com%252Fpage%252Fblabla%0D%0A
```